# google cloud storage - getting started

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow GCS getting started guide - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

it says that I should download the client library, i did it with git.

then it says:

> In the Libraries tab, click Add External Jars. You must add the
>   following JARs:
>
> appengine-gcs-client.jar from wherever you installed the Cloud Storage
>   client library
>
> guava-15.0.jar from wherever you installed the Cloud Storage client
>   library
>
> joda-time-2.3.jar from wherever you installed the Cloud Storage client
>   library
>
> appengine-testing.jar from the App Engine install subdirectory
>   /lib/testing.
>
> appengine-api.jar from the App Engine install subdirectory /lib/impl.
>
> appengine-api-stubs.jar from the App Engine install subdirectory
>   /lib/impl.

but there are absolutly no jars in the download,

what am I missing??

Edit:
I manage to find the missing jars on the web, now i get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   com.google.appengine.spi.FactoryProvider: Provider
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.ISearchServiceFactoryProvider could
>   not be instantiated   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)    at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory$1.run(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:148)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory$1.run(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:130)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory.getProvidersUsingServiceLoader(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:130)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory.access$100(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:39)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory$RuntimeRegistry.(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:109)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.spi.ServiceFactoryFactory.getFactory(ServiceFactoryFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getFactory(DatastoreServiceFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactory.java:20)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.(LocalRawGcsService.java:87)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsServiceFactory.createLocalRawGcsService(LocalRawGcsServiceFactory.java:29)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:44)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.demos.LocalExample.(LocalExample.java:54)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.demos.LocalExample.main(LocalExample.java:129)
>   Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchServicePb$DeleteDocumentRequest
>   overrides final method
>   getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchServiceFactoryImpl.(SearchServiceFactoryImpl.java:13)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.search.ISearchServiceFactoryProvider.(ISearchServiceFactoryProvider.java:16)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)     ...
>   18 more

Seems like this guide was never actually tested, and is a complete waste of time, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same troubles and what worked for me:

1. Updated the libraries (appengine + appengine-testing) to the same version

   - I used to have appengine version 1.9.18 and appenginte-testing version 1.4.0. Now I have both version 1.9.25 (the latest at the moment)
2. Added all necessary libraries

   - appengine-api-labs and appengine-api-stubs were missing

My build.gradle config now contains this:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.25'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.25'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.25'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.25'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.25'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.25'

}
```